# Linkage error using gtest in eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, googletest

I'm trying to use gtest in my cpp project, and there's probably a linkage error. 
It also does not recognize the main that is in test folder.

```
Building target: MovieSystem
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "MovieSystem"  ./src/Actor.o ./src/Director.o ./src/Menu.o ./src/Movie.o ./src/Producer.o ./src/Professional.o ./src/ScreenWriter.o ./src/System.o ./src/factorial.o   -lpthread

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
...
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':

(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MovieSystem] Error 1
```

Just to mention, I followed the instructions in here completely:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811934/Cplusplus-unit-test-start-guide-how-to-set-up-Goog

So what did I do wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: did you define a main function for yur test?

Comment: yes - it's in the test folder.

Comment: neither the code of main fuction nor the gtest library are included in your linkage command

Comment: so how do i fix it? i did add the libraries to the include paths

Comment: Look for gcc reference on the `-l` and `-L` options. Eclipse projects should also have some settings for library paths which actually end up being the parameters for `-l` and `-L` command line options when Eclipse calls gcc.

Comment: problem solved. it appears that the problem was i opened it as a ''hello world'' eclipse's project and edited it, and somewhy eclipse doesnt look for source files in other directories apart from src. weird, but that's it. thank you all